# How to make a JavaFX Chat Application using Sockets?

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a Chat Application that I can use to send messages to other computers over a LAN connection. I am new to Java Networking, and the Socket tutorials I have found online aren't doing me many favors.

I have coded the visuals of the app itself, but I would like to be able to connect clients to the same server and display the messages on each device.

Sockets and networking have confused me a bit, and I have tried following a few online tutorials and web pages about sockets with no luck.

Here is the code for the visuals of the application.

```java
public class cli {

    static Stage window;
    static Pane layout = new Pane();
    static Scene scene;
    static String name;
    public static String message;
    static TextArea a = new TextArea();
    DataInputStream din;
    DataInputStream dout;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    public static void display() throws Exception {

        scene  = new Scene(layout, 500, 500);

        Stage window = new Stage();
        System.out.println("Enter a username!");
        window.setScene(scene);

        TextField t = new TextField();
        Button send = new Button("Send");
        TextArea log = new TextArea();
        log.setVisible(false);
        log.setEditable(false);

        a.setEditable(false);
        a.setTranslateX(50);
        a.setTranslateY(25);
        a.setMaxWidth(400);
        a.setMaxHeight(450);
        a.setMinHeight(450);
        t.setMaxHeight(20);
        t.setMaxWidth(350);
        send.setMaxWidth(50);
        t.setLayoutY(445);
        send.setLayoutY(445);
        t.setLayoutX(55);
        t.setMinWidth(340);
        send.setLayoutX(400);

        a.appendText("Group chat started at " + new Date() + "!" + "\n");
        a.appendText("Current Members: " + "\n");
        send.setOnAction(e -> {
            message = t.getText();
            System.out.println(message);
            if (message != null && message.length() >= 1) {
                a.appendText("[Client]" + " -> " + message + "\n");
                log.appendText("[Client] @ " + new Date() + " -> " + message + "\n");
            } else {

            }
        });


        layout.getChildren().addAll(a, t, send);
        window.show();
}
}
```

It should look something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/liHcZ.jpg

Essentially, I want each connected client to have their own app window, and whenever a user types something it sends that message to each client.

If someone could walk me through this that'd be really helpful. Thanks! :)

Comment: I reccommend to try a P2P library for that. You can try for instance https://github.com/BFergerson/Beam

Comment: @Mihai8 I've never used a github library like that, it doesn't seem to have a designated jar file, so how would I import that to my project's build path?

*Sorry for the dumb question*

Comment: You can try to integrate source code of that library directly in your application, that can be one of method.

Comment: Sample [cli chat app using websockets](https://github.com/benas/web-socket-lab), you could adapt it to work with JavaFX using a similar technique to this [JavaFX websocket test](https://github.com/jewelsea/javafx-websocket-test), with a bit of work and a lot of care about how threads function.